# Magento Newly created module giving error when deploy on live domain

Tags: magento, module

Magento Newly created module is giving an error when deployed on my live domain.
The error is:

**2014-01-09T19:33:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Orderevent/Myobserver/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home3/myvoice3/public_html/shop/app/code/local:/home3/myvoice3/public_html/shop/app/code/community:/home3/myvoice3/public_html/shop/app/code/core:/home3/myvoice3/public_html/shop/lib:.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear')  in /home3/myvoice3/public_html/shop/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93**

```
My module  config file (OrderEvent_MyObserver.xml)
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <OrderEvent_MyObserver>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <active>true</active>
            </OrderEvent_MyObserver>
        </modules>
    </config>



My module config file.

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <OrderEvent_MyObserver>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </OrderEvent_MyObserver>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <ordereventmyobserver>
                    <class>MyObserver_Model</class>
                </ordereventmyobserver>
            </models>
            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>orderevent_myobserver_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>create_order_netsuite</method>
                        </orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after> 
            <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <observers>
                        <orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>orderevent_myobserver_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>create_invoice_netsuite</method>
                        </orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                    </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>


            <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                        <orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>orderevent_myobserver_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>add_customer</method>
                        </orderevent_myobserver_model_observer>
                    </observers>
            </customer_save_after>



            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Comment: would you please include the code snippet where you are calling the Observer ?

Comment: @AftabNaveed i have updated the issue. Its is working fine locally. i don't know why its not working on live.

Comment: When observer trigger from front end magento shows me the error (http://myvoiceclip.com/record/Magento-issue-of-accessing-module.png)